# What is the basic operation of merge sort and how do I find a recurrence relation for the basic step in the best case

Tags: c, algorithm, mergesort, recurrence

I am analyzing merge sort in `C` programming, I don't understand what will be the `basic operation` for the algorithm and how do I setup and `recurrence relation` for that basic step (best case)!?

I think the basic operation will be the `comparison step` which has been commented as basic operation.
If it is then how do I setup and `recurrence relation` for that step?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// lets take a[5] = { 32, 45, 67, 2, 7 } as the array to be sorted.

// merge sort function
void mergeSort(int a[], int p, int r)
{
    int q;
    if (p < r)
    {
        q = (p + r) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, p, q);
        mergeSort(a, q + 1, r);
        merge(a, p, q, r);
    }
}

// function to merge the subarrays
void merge(int a[], int p, int q, int r)
{
    int b[5];   //same size of a[]
    int i, j, k;
    k = 0;
    i = p;
    j = q + 1;
    while (i <= q && j <= r)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[j])  //basic operation
        {
            b[k++] = a[i++];    // same as b[k]=a[i]; k++; i++;
        }
        else
        {
            b[k++] = a[j++];
        }
    }
  
    while (i <= q)
    {
        b[k++] = a[i++];
    }
  
    while (j <= r)
    {
        b[k++] = a[j++];
    }
  
    for (i = r; i >= p; i--)
    {
        a[i] = b[--k];  // copying back the sorted list to a[]
    } 
}
```

Comment: [style] I would start by using more descriptive identifiers.

Comment: The recurrence relation (not present in your fragment) is **1)** sort the left halve **2)** sort the right halve **3)** merge the two halves. Your code only contains **(3)** [and I *think* there are a few off-by-one errors in it]

Answer (score 0):

A few hints:

- The recurrence relation (not present in your fragment) is:

  1. sort the left half
  2. sort the right half
  3. merge the two halfes.
- decide which arguments to pass, either the *midpoint* and the total size, or the left size and the right size.
- decide if the sizes include the final element or not
- prefer unsigned data types for sizes and indexes; these can never be negative.
- The merge() function only needs three arguments; the recursive calls don't need to pass a pointer to the first element of the array, but can be given a pointer somewhere inside the array.
- you don't need a complete copy of the array, you need it only for one half of it.

---

```
void merge(int array[], unsigned lsiz, unsigned rsiz)
{
    unsigned lpos, rpos, totpos, totsiz;
    int *spare;

    if (lsiz > 1) { // recurse: sort the left side
        unsigned half;
        half = lsiz /2;
        merge(array, half, lsiz - half);
    }

    if (rsiz > 1) { // recurse: sort the right side
        unsigned half;
        half = rsiz /2;
        merge(array+lsiz, half, rsiz - half);
    }

    /*
    ** allocate a copy of the left side
    ** , so that we can merge *in place*
    */
    spare = malloc(sizeof *array * lsiz);
    if (!spare) return;
    memcpy(spare, array, sizeof *spare *lsiz);

    totsiz = lsiz + rsiz;
    lpos = 0;
    rpos = lsiz;

#if 0

    for (totpos = 0; lpos < lsiz && rpos < totsiz; totpos++) {
        if (spare[lpos] <= array[rpos]) { array[totpos] = spare[lpos++];}
        else { array[totpos] = array[rpos++]; }
    }
    while (lpos < lsiz)  {array[totpos++] = spare[lpos++]; }
    while (rpos < totsiz) {array[totpos++] = array[rpos++]; }

#else

    for (totpos = 0; totpos < totsiz; totpos++) {
        if (lpos >= lsiz) goto right;
        if (rpos >= totsiz) goto left;
        if (spare[lpos] > array[rpos]) goto right;
      left:
        array[totpos] = spare[lpos++];
        continue;
      right:
        array[totpos] = array[rpos++];
        continue;
    }

#endif

    free(spare);
}
```

---

Note: I kept the `goto` version, because I think it is actually more readable.

Comment: For real use please reconsider your use of the malloc's, do we really need that many mallocs?

Comment: No, you could do with a single (half size) stash. But that would require more bookkeeping. [and thus: complicate the demo-program]

Answer (score 0):

Since the above answers provide code for the process, I'm just addressing the thought process behind the same for a general class of problems. This is a classic example of a [Divide and Conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) problem. The complexity analysis of such problem relies on identifying the complexity of these 3 operations

1. Divide: This is the the amount of work that you do to divide your problem into sub-problems. In the case of merge sort this is the step involved in dividing the array into 2 equal length sub-arrays. The complexity of this step would be *O(1)* as it involves finding a mid point of the array.
2. Conquer: This step would involve solving the sub-problems created by the above step. So here the sub-problems are to sort 2 arrays of size half of the original size.
3. Combine: This step involves combining results of sub-problems to find the result for the original problem, which in this case would reduce to the problem of creating a sorted array from 2 sub-arrays that are sorted, which is what is being done by the merge function. The complexity of this step would be linear in terms of the size of the segment.

So if **T(n**) is the complexity of sorting an array of size **n**,
**T(n/2)** would be the complexity of sorting a segment of size **n/2**. Now if I were to express the complexity in terms of aforementioned 3 steps if would look like

> **T(n) = O(1) + 2 * T(n/2) + O(n)**

which can be solved using [Master's Theorem](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/master-theorem), the complexity comes out as **O(nlog(n))**